# How do I cancel a request in Taleo Connect Client?

Tags: taleo, taleo-connect-client

I have an Export request in Taleo Connect Client which has been running for several minutes without a response. I'd like to cancel my request so I can make changes.

How do I cancel an active request in Taleo Connect Client?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to cancel a running process is from a "Profile" on Taleo Connect Server (File > New Profile Wizard). From there you will see a list of all the processes that were submitted to the server. If a process is running, you can select it in the list and click on the "Pause" button to stop it:

[image]